# How to create a List message for whatsapp using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

How to create a List message for whatsapp using Twilio

How to create a List message for whatsapp using Twilio

Comment: Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What did you already try and where are you stuck? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Twilio only supports [templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons) with **quick reply buttons** or **call to actions**. This might be a good alternative if you have only a few options.

[image: cta and quick reply]

I know this is not perfect and hopefully there will be more message types in the future.